# Removing empty column from csv file using c#

Tags: c#, csv

I have csv file which contain the data

```
   ABC,BCA,AAA 
   CBA,BSH,updated 
   XYZ



   ,Marketing,YYY
```

I tried with the below code but am getting the result as

Result:-

```
 ABC,BCA,AAA 
 CBA,BSH,updated 
 XYZ
    ,Marketing,YYY
```

Code:-

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace RemoveEmptyLines
    {
       class Program
        {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string path = @"C:\Users\Test\Downloads\222.csv";
        Test test = new Test();
        test.RemoveBlankRowsFromCVSFile(path);      
    }

   }}

   public class Test
    {
       public void RemoveBlankRowsFromCVSFile(string filepath)
         {
              if (filepath == null || filepath.Length == 0)
                  {
                     throw new ArgumentNullException("filepath");
                   }

               if (!File.Exists(filepath))
                  {
                   throw new FileNotFoundException("Could not find CVS      file.", filepath);
                   }

    var tempFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
    try
    {
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(filepath))
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(tempFileName))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                {
                    streamWriter.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }
        File.Copy(tempFileName, filepath, true);
    }
    finally
    {
        File.Delete(tempFileName);
    }
}}
```

But i want the output like,

```
ABC,BCA,AAA 
CBA,BSH,updated 
XYZ,Marketing,YYY
```

Kindly help me with this,Thanks in advance.

Is there any way so that i can get the desired result.

Comment: The file which you call a csv is not a valid csv, so let's not call it that

Comment: The trouble is that the CSV file is incorrect to begin with. You should fix whatever is creating the CSV file in the first place. It is a valid CSV (as such), but it's not valid for your purpose given that a line feed is being entered into it. Fix the original CSV, not the symptoms. If you can't, then you'll have to just check each row to ensure that it has 3 non-empty values and if not, read them from the next line.

Comment: Ya ya that is correct that is not a valid csv file and i have corrected the csv file

Comment: @VenkateshVenky I don't think you understand. It's still not correct. The line breaks is what makes it incorrect. Your question has nothing to do with csv files, it has to do with formatting text

Comment: Hi @Joe Philllips Please now you check the csv file.

Comment: @VenkateshVenky The solution is to output a valid CSV file in the first place. You are going to run into a lot of issues by trying to "fix" a file and turn it into a valid CSV file

Comment: Is this csv being made from another source format where partial parsing has been applied causing these undesired artefacts to show up in csv?

Answer (score 0):

- Updated with new data. But all suggestions stay the same

This is not a solution, but a suggestion to actually get you to a solution:

1. This can't be done properly without knowing in advance how many columns are expected in each row and after that also the resultant solution as the question stands will be inadequate: Your data is still not in correct CSV format

Please see here for an acceptable CSV format: http://edoceo.com/utilitas/csv-file-format

2. Even after you know the number of columns it seems that the result you are asking for is to remove empty rows and merge data from one row into another row if the previous data is incorrect.

Case in point:

```
ABC,BCA,AAA 
CBA,BSH,updated 
XYZ



,Marketing,YYY
```

Expected result:

```
ABC,BCA,AAA 
CBA,BSH,updated 
XYZ,Marketing,YYY
```

What you are asking with that request is this:

- Remove empty rows
- Remove whitespaces (including unescaped newlines)
- Merge multiple rows of data into 1 row

  3. This causes a ton of other problems.

E.g. What is expected here:

```
A,,
,B,
C,D,E
```

or here:

```
A,B
,,C,D
```

or here:

```
A,B,C
,,D,
E,F,G
```

or here:

```
A,B,
C,D,E
```

or here:

```
A,B
C,D,E
```

or here

```
A,B,C
D

E,

F G H
, I
```

4. The only case where I can see this as a real and reliable input data is where there is more information that hasn't been provided to help solve the problem: about the file format and how the data within the columns has been structured.

Hence, possible way forward:

- The problem is partially stated with a lot of ambiguities. Please
  restate.
- If this is a real life issue then like @joe-philllips said
  fix the data generator.
- Look at the problem differently and identify
  how best you can identify newlines and other malformations and escape
  those properly and write a proper CSV parser instead of attempting to
  get all content on one line.

Answer (score 0):

this will help to you:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace CSVFixer
{
    public class CSV
    {
        public void fixCSV(string filePath)
        {
            string content = File.ReadAllText(filePath, Encoding.UTF8);
            string reEx = "\\r\\n\\s+";
            content = Regex.Replace(content, reEx,"");                       
            File.WriteAllText(filePath, content, Encoding.UTF8);            
        }
    }
}
```

You only need to pass the prameter.

```
string filePath = @"C:\Users\Ivan\Documents\csv.txt";
```

May be you need to modify the regular expresion called reEx and it would work well if your file is .csv also.